# 403 Access Denied Error while creating a dataset in DOMO

Tags: api, domo

I'm getting an 404 access denied error while trying to create a dataset in DOMO, anyone who is good in DOMO please help me,

```
import logging
from pydomo import Domo
from pydomo.datasets import DataSetRequest, Schema, Column, ColumnType, Policy
from pydomo.datasets import PolicyFilter, FilterOperator, PolicyType, Sorting

client_id = ''
client_secret_code = ''
data_set_id = ''
api_host = 'api.domo.com'
domo = Domo(client_id, client_secret_code, logger_name='foo', log_level=logging.INFO, 
api_host=api_host)
data_set_name = 'Testing'
data_set_description = 'Test_to_update_schema'

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)

domo = Domo(client_id, client_secret_code, logger_name='foo', log_level=logging.INFO, 
api_host=api_host)

dsr = DataSetRequest()
dsr.name = data_set_name
dsr.description = data_set_description
dsr.schema = Schema([Column(ColumnType.STRING, 'Id'),
Column(ColumnType.STRING, 'Publisher_Name')])
dataset = domo.datasets.create(dsr)
print(dataset)
```

Comment: The error I'm getting is 'Exception: Error creating DataSet: {"status":403,"statusReason":"Forbidden","message":"Access is denied","toe":"I4AIQ9KDVU-0783U-D4F14"}'

Answer (score 2):

This is Authorization error. Either of credentials are wrong that is client_id, client_secret_code or maybe both.

Comment: Credentials aren't wrong, we fix errors and successfully pull data from DOMO to google spreadsheet. In the end, we did it with the Google Apps script, it's similar to code to Typescript and everything goes well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error in .NET when using Domo to connect and get data from the dataset. I fix this when I create a base64 string and passed it to auth for example Authorization is Basic
"Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}"))

I am not sure how this goes in Python but create a base64 string and pass for auth.